# MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) wifi just capitulated

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, bluetooth

I got a 16-inch MacBook Pro (A2141) with 32GB ram and a Core i9 (I9-9980HK) 2.4 GHz processor. When I turned it on in the morning it required a first-time password despite I put it to sleep the night before, and the time setting was off with several hours.

The wifi and bluetooth button is actually disabled, both in the bar and system setting, I'm unable to turn them on in any possible way.

[image]

I manually set the time and restarted the computer, but the wifi/bluethoot issues remain.

I tried NVRAM and SMC reset, but that's not worked either. I also tried to boot in safe mode, but wifi and bluetooth do not work in safe mode either.

The `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off/networksetup -setairportpower airport off` commands are result in the same error message:

> airport is not a Wi-Fi interface.
> ** Error: Error obtaining wireless information.

The `networksetup -listallhardwareports` does not show any evidence that wifi actually exists in my system

Is this a software issue or purely hardware related? What can I do to further investigate, and if it's a software issue, can I fix it?

Comment: Boot to Safe Mode, if it can’t find your AirPort card there, it’s hardware.

Comment: See this existing answer similar to your issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325342/119271

Comment: Thank @Allan, the AirPort card on the newer models is directly integrated into the main board am I right, so the "loose" connection in this scenario means permanent hardware damage?

Comment: The antenna is still a cable, but you are correct.  If the AirPort chip or the circuitry that supports it has died, you’ll need board level repair.  It can be fixed, but you”ll have to send it off. It’s not DIY.